# new role which can query snowflake account usage, without account admin role

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I would like a new role which can query snowflake account usage. Currently only Account Admin have this  privilege and don’t want to assign Account Admin for required users.

Comment: Do you mean the SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE schema? If so, then this is clearly described in the documentation

Comment: Thanks Nick for swift reply, are you talking about with use of imported privileges ? if it is SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE schema.

and what if its not to use of SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE schema and still wanted to know the account usage of snowflake ? is that possible ? if yes what are the ways without ac. admin role ?

Comment: Hi, you’ll need to explain precisely what you mean by “the account usage of snowflake” in order for anyone to help you. If you are not talking about the contents if the ACCOUNT_USAGE schema then what are you talking about?

Comment: @NickW looks like enough information to dig more in it now, thanks for your help.
probably I will collect more details on my question/requirement and get back to you !
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IMPORTED PRIVILEGES grant would allow a non-admin role access to the SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE schemas ([docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#enabling-snowflake-database-usage-for-other-roles)).   There is also a MONITOR USAGE global grant which allows similar billing and usage monitoring but through information_schema functions instead. See the documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-configure.html#label-allow-other-users-to-monitor-usage-billing-history) -- particularly the table is helpful to explain the differences between these two options.

These are some of the more common built-in grant options for a billing-monitoring role, but if you need a more custom solution, you can always create some custom SQL (perhaps stored procedure and task for maintenance) that copies only the desired admin results from ACCOUNT_USAGE to a custom table/view.  Then you can grant access to that custom object to your non-admins.

Comment: that's very helpful info, probably I will work on this suggestions practically in dev env and will implement this, Thanks.